# PHP - Redirect page

Tags: php, authentication

All,

I have few html pages in my application which is on WAMP.

I needed an login page which on successful login would redirect the user to the other page in the application.

I am:

1> Not able to redirect. I have define the `header('Location: /X/Y/abc.html')`. This is the relative path from the wamp home i.e. `C:\wamp\www\`. I think there is a issue with the path being mentioned here.

2> On unsuccessful login, the user should be redirect to the same page. When I tried that using `header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])`. Trying to execute the code gives me

So I have 2 folders essentially:

Folder Z contains the following HTML code named `index.html` and abc.php
Folder /X/Y/ contains the actual application for which the authentication is set.

HTML Code:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>
         Login
      </title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action="/Z/abc.php" method="post">
         <table id="input">
         <tr>
               <td>Admin Username <input type="text" name="username"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
               <td>Password <input type="text" name="passwd"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
               <td><input type = "submit" id="submitButton"></td>
         </tr>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php 
   $username="ab";
   $password="cd";

   if (isset($_POST["username"]) && strcasecmp($username, $_POST["username"]))
   {
      header('Location: /X/Y/navigation.html');
   }
?>
```

Executing the code doesn't redirect me to the `navigation.html` but stops at abc.php i.e. the URL remaind: http://localhost:81/Z/validate.php

Comment: The redirect to '/X/Y/abc.html' should work as a relative root, as long as you can hit 'http://server/X/Y/abc.html'.  It doesn't matter where anything is installed.

Are you doing the redirect before you've sent anything else to the buffer?

Comment: "Trying to execute the code gives me"...?

Comment: Call exit() after the header, because calling header() does not end the script. You are probably rewriting the HTTP 302 with something else later in the script.

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work. Still stuck at `abc.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to make your abc.php redirect back to the login page if the login isn't successful:

abc.php:

```
<?php

$username = 'ab';
$password = 'cd';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   if ((isset($_POST['username']) && ($_POST['username'] == $username)) &&
      (isset($_POST['password']) && ($_POST['password'] == $password))) {
         header("Location: /X/Y/navigation.html");
         exit();
   }
}

header("Location: login.html");
```